# How to change default Date format for html5 input type="date"

Tags: html, date-format

We have Default date type  in HTML5. It has some default date format like 
mm/dd/yy. ( eg. 05/21/88). i want to change this date format as per my requirement dynamically. is there any option for this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Answer (score 1):

You could have a hidden field right before the datefield and create a onchange event on the date field that runs a javascript call, which converts the date format into your preferred format and stores it into the hidden field.

You use a datepicker from one of these [javascript libraries](http://www.codeanddesign-studio.com/2011/03/02/40-free-date-and-time-pickers/). Most of these libraries have possibilities to change dateformat.

Comment: Yes Stian Standahl. but is it not possible to display date field itself?

Comment: After reading up on it. It doesn't look like it is possible to show a different dateformat. If you use this date input it will not be fully supported by all browsers. (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp). I would recommend using jquery UI (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) where you can change the dateformat.

Comment: ya that is fine. but actually in this plugin we dont have year wise navigation right?

Comment: here is a list of different javascript libraries that gives you datepicking possibility. http://www.codeanddesign-studio.com/2011/03/02/40-free-date-and-time-pickers/

Comment: can you set my answer as solution? do you have a short explanation on how you solved the problem, and possibly which javascript library you used?